# Determine a Generating Series of a Composition

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Question:
Let H be the set of compositions  = $\{c_{1},c_{2},c_{3},....c_{k}\}$ of any length,
in which each part $\{c_{b}\}$ is congruent to b (modulo 2). Determine a rational function formula for the generating series of the set H.

Solution Attempt:

It's obvious that the element in $\{c_{1},c_{3},....c_{2i+1}\}$ are odd, and that the elements in $\{c_{2},c_{4},....c_{2i}\}$ are even.

The generating series for a set where all elements are even is given by $\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$, and the generating series for a set where all the elements are odd is given by $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$. The part where I'm stuck is determine how to combine these series for a composition of total length of $k$.

Comment: Are these compositions supposed to sum to a number $n$?

Comment: Yes, these compositions should sum to a number $n$ @AlanAbraham

Comment: So you want to find a generating function $h(x)$ such that the coefficient of $x^n$ is the number of compositions of $n$ that follow those rules? If so, you might want to consider how we derive the generating function for the same problem but without the additional constraints.

Comment: Concatenation of objects corresponds to the product of ordinary generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

We show a generating function $A(x)$ for the number of compositions starting with an odd term and continuing with terms of alternating parity is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{A(x)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{x}{1-2x^2-x^3+x^4}}\\
&=x + 2 x^3 + x^4 + \color{blue}{3} x^5 + \color{blue}{4} x^6 + 5 x^7\\
&\qquad + 10 x^8 + 11 x^9 + 21 x^{10} + 27 x^{11} + \cdots\tag{1}
\end{align*}

At first we look at small examples $n=5$ and $n=6$. We list the partitions $p$ of $n$ in the first column, give the number $c(p)$ of compositions of the partition $p$ in the second column and count the number $w(p)$ of wanted compositions in the third column.

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{lcc}
p&c(p)&w(p)\\
\hline
5&\quad 1&\quad 1\\
4+1&\quad 2&\quad 1\\
3+2&\quad 2&\quad 1\\
3+1+1&\quad 3&\quad 0\\
2+2+1&\quad 3&\quad 0\\
2+1+1+1&\quad 4&\quad 0\\
1+1+1+1+1&\quad 1&\quad 0\\
\hline
&2^4=16&\quad \color{blue}{3}\\
\\
p&c(p)&w(p)\\
\hline
6&1&0\\
5+1&2&0\\
4+2&2&0\\
4+1+1&3&1\\
3+3&1&0\\
3+2+1&6&2\\
3+1+1+1&4&0\\
2+2+2&1&0\\
2+2+1+1&6&1\\
2+1+1+1+1&5&0\\
1+1+1+1+1+1&1&0\\
\hline
&2^5=32&\color{blue}{4}
\end{array}
\end{align*}

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. We observe from the tables above in accordance with (1)
\begin{align*}
[x^5]A(x)=\color{blue}{3}\qquad\qquad[x^6]A(x)=\color{blue}{4}
\end{align*}

> **Odd terms:** In order to build up the generating series $A(x)$ we split the valid compositions into two parts. The first part contains the odd terms with generating function $O(x;s)$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{O(x;s)}&=\sum_{q=1}^\infty\left(x+x^3+x^5+\cdots\right)^qs^q\\
> &=\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{xs}{1-x^2}\right)^q\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{xs}{1-sx-x^2}}
> \end{align*}

We use a variable $s$ as marker for the *number* of odd terms a valid composition contains. A valid composition of the number $n$ containing precisely $k$ odd terms is consequently
\begin{align*}
[x^ns^k]O(x;s)&=[x^ns^k]\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{xs}{1-x^2}\right)^q\\
&=[x^n]\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\right)^k
\end{align*}

> **Even terms:** The second part contains the even terms with generating function $E(x;t)$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{E(x;t)}&=\sum_{q=1}^\infty\left(x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots\right)^qt^q\\
> &=\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^2t}{1-x^2}\right)^q\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{x^2t}{1-x^2(1+t)}}
> \end{align*}

We use a variable $t$ as marker for the *number* of even terms a valid composition contains. A valid composition of the number $n$ containing precisely $k$ even terms is consequently
\begin{align*}
[x^nt^k]E(x;t)&=[x^nt^k]\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^2t}{1-x^2}\right)^q\\
&=[x^n]\left(\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\right)^k
\end{align*}

Valid compositions consist of either an even number $2k$ of terms, which means $k$ odd numbers and $k$ even numbers starting with an odd number and ending with an even number or they consist of an odd number $2k+1$ of terms, which means $k+1$ odd numbers and $k$ even numbers starting and ending with an odd number.

> **$2k$ terms:**
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty}&\color{blue}{[s^kt^k]\left(O(x)E(x)\right)}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\right)^k\left(\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\right)^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{3k}}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{2k}}\\
> &=\frac{\frac{x^3}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}}{1-\frac{x^3}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{x^3}{1-2x^2-x^3+x^4}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> **$2k+1$ terms:**
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty}&\color{blue}{[s^{k+1}t^k]\left(O(x)E(x)\right)}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\right)^{k+1}\left(\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\right)^k\\
> &=\frac{x}{1-x^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3k}}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{2k}}\\
> &=\frac{x}{1-x^2}\,\frac{1}{1-\frac{x^3}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{x-x^3}{1-2x^2-x^3+x^4}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> Adding (2) and (3) we finally obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(x)=\frac{x}{1-2x^2-x^3+x^4}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.